# use of the interjection "but lo' ..."

Tags: meaning, interjections

In an article I tried to understand (the german understanding) of:

> (...) we’re outside the part of ***C*** where the standard Dirichlet series actually converges. But lo’ we can ask what’s the Ramanujan summation (...)

Here the interjection *lo'* got my interest. I found, for instance *lo and behold* in leo.org and thus I think I understand the meaning here, too.

But is there some root of that interjection (semantic, etymological,...)? I mean, the author has added an apostrophe so something should be behind it; Leo.org does not help here.

Comment: Related: [How to use “lo and behold” expression](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5068/).

Comment: @JSBangs: Hi, thanks for the corrections *(my written english has become even worse than my oral english...)*

Comment: @Gottfried: What do you mean by *german understanding*? Did you mean *German* or *germane*?

Comment: @Jimi: "German", sorry. (Would "germane" mean something meaningful here, btw?)

Comment: @Gottfried Helms - it's from Romeo&Juliet "But lo, what light through yonder window shines. It is the east and Juliet..." So it's being used as a general expression of surprise (like ah-ah). The writer here is trying a sort of joke - read it as "but <surprise> we can ask"

Comment: @Gottfried Helms, germane means relevant to the question/discussion. So here, your name being Gottfried is germane to the question of whether you meant germane or German !

Comment: @mgb:+1 for making me lough :-)

Comment: Sorry I was late to respond. Thanks @mgb for helping me out! *Germane* could actually work in this question—there could be different understandings, but only one would be relevant. I became even more confused when I found out that *german* is the archaic spelling of *germane*!

Comment: @Jimi - even more confusing, although germane has nothing to do with Deutschland (it's from the latin for `same parents`) it is used as an adjective for German in some languages where the word for Deutschland isn't Germany.

Comment: @mgb: Wow, interesting!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have never seen it with an apostrophe. I'm guessing the author is under the impression that it is short for "look!". It isn't

According to the OED, in Middle English there are two distinct words "lo" or "loo" which have fallen together; one of them is indeed derived from a form of "look", but the other "lá, an exclamation indicating surprise, grief, or joy".

Comment: Isn't "loo" a synonym of toilet as well? :D

Answer (score 4):

From [TheFreeOnlineDictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lo):

> **lo** Used to attract attention or show surprise.

You don't need the apostrophe. In fact, don't use it. you can use an exclamation point, however, even in the middle of a sentence.

Comment: (I'm sure there's actually a question here about it being OK to use the exclamation point in the middle of a sentence if you search.)

Answer (score 2):

In older English usage you will also find the word *lo* used with other conjunctions such as *and*, as in the expression, "*And lo*, there was...".

Comment: “And there were in the same country shepherds abiding in the field, ... And lo, the angel of the Lord came upon them, and the glory of the Lord shone ...." - From the Book of Luke in The New Testament.